# Tastypie - Filtering by related pk

Tags: python, tastypie

I would like to filter a resource via a related field pk.

For example, I have the country pk and I would like to get all cities from that country. How could I do that?

```
class CityResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = City.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'city'
        fields = ['name','id']

        filtering = {
           #Something here
        }

class CountryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Country.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'country'
        fields = ['name','code2','id']
```

And a example URL:

```
http://startuprepublik.pre.is/api/v1/city/?format=json&country__pk=4
```

Any idea?

Comment: You have country ForeignKey on your City model right?

Comment: Yes. I'm using cities_light. https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light/blob/master/cities_light/models.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from tastypie.fields import ForeignKey
from tastypie.resources import ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

class CityResource(ModelResource):
    country = ForeignKey("path.to.api.CountryResource", "country")

    class Meta:
        queryset = City.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'city'
        fields = ['name','id']

        filtering = {
           "country": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

class CountryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Country.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'country'
        fields = ['name','code2','id']
        filtering = { "id": ALL }
```

Comment: Hi Issac. I get this response > The 'country' field does not allow filtering. I've tried to add a filtering var on CountryResource but I got the same results.

Comment: Ok. I solved it, seems it didn't restart the server or something. If I add:

filtering = {
           "id":  ALL,
        }

It fixes the problem, can you update your answer so I can mark it as the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mc-, this comment saved me